# How to write 2 two-dimensional array to json object in java using json-simple?

Tags: java, json-simple

I'm setting up a java game server request handler that get json messages and send back relevant json message as response. 
In some cases I need to send 2 dimensional String array as the game board. 
I'm having a problem to do that using json-simple. 
Further more, how to parse it to a board in the client side afterwards? Thanks.

```
char[][] charArray; //initialised  
JSONObject jsonOut = new JSONObject();
ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray() ;

ja.add(charArray);
jsonOut.put("board", ja);
writer.writeObject(jsonOut);
```

getting exception while ja.add(charArray);

Comment: Please state the nature of the "problem" you are having: what *specific" exception are you getting  (a stack trace would be nice).

Comment: Add the exception message stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to add an entire `char[][]` array as a single element in `JSONArray`. You need to create a multi-dimensional `JSONArray` and map the `char[][]` character-by-character:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
for (char[] ca : charArray) {
  JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
  for (char c : ca) {
    arr.add(Character.toString(c)); // or some other conversion
  }
  jsonArray.add(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a JsonArray of JsonArrays, the same way your String[][] is an array of arrays.